# Yii: On validation error: Need to preserve the selected country and city

Tags: php, yii

I'm working on signup form and I have 2 steps to user register in some website, so step 1 is a create action and step 2 is update action on profile controller.

so my problem is how can preserve the selected country and city on validation error but it's already  ?! check the image

[image: Check this]

view:

```
<div class="row">


        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'countryId'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'countryId',
                CHtml::listData(SysCountry::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'),
                array(
                    'empty'=>'Select country',
                    'ajax' => array(
                    'type'=>'POST', //request type
                    'url'=>CController::createUrl('profile/dynamiccity'), //url to call.
                    //Style: CController::createUrl('currentController/methodToCall')
                    'update'=>'#Profile_cityId', //selector to update
                    //'data'=>'js:javascript statement' 
                    //leave out the data key to pass all form values through
                    )));

        ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'countryId'); ?> 
</div>


<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'cityId'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'cityId', array('empty'=>'Please select country first')
        ); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'cityId'); ?> 
    </div>
```

Comment: can you show your create and update function in the controller?

Comment: ok.. I do it,  I will add the solution soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, to update the second drop down you need to use

```
'update'=>'#'.CHtml::activeId($model,'tracanton'),

echo CActiveForm::dropDownList
                     (
                        $model,'traprovincia',
                        CHtml::listData
                        ( 
                            CatUbicacionGeografica::model()->findAll('cat_ubigeo_nivel=? ORDER BY cat_ubigeo_descripcion', array('2') ), 
                            'cat_ubigeo_codigo', 'cat_ubigeo_descripcion'
                        ), 
                         array(
                            'ajax'=>array(
                                'type' => 'POST',
                                'url' => CController::createUrl('tramite/updatecanton'),
                                'data'=>array('padre'=>'js:this.value'), 
                                'update'=>'#'.CHtml::activeId($model,'tracanton'),
                                ),
                             'prompt' => '( Seleccione Provincia )',
                             'style' => "width: 300px;",
                            // 'onchange'=>'js:$("#tracanton").focus()',
                        )    
                     );
```

Comment: recheck the question before you answer, this question is about preserving form field values between server validation calls, not about how to populate dependent drop-downs! don't know why this was upvoted

Comment: Are you certain you posted the right answer on the right question?

Answer (score 0):

Is it javascript or PHP validation? If its the former use JS to take the values of the dropdown boxes and then repopulate (ikll post some code if its this). If its PHP then do the following on your drop downs

```
<select>

//-- If 'save' has been entered and validation has been caught
if (isset($_POST/GET['country'])) {

  echo '<option value=". $_POST/GET['country'] . '" selected="selected">' . $_POST/GET['country'] . '</option>';

} else {

   //-- if validation hasnt been actioned

}

</select>
```

Whilst this may not work for your code i hope you get the idea. If you can post your validation code ill be able to amend properly so it works for you.